# Check if PowerShell SecureString has a value

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to verify that a user entered password stored as a `SecureString` is not blank.

Currently I am checking the length (i.e., `if ($password.Length -eq 0) { # prompt again }`) and that seems to work. If that's the "correct" way to do it, great.  Otherwise I want to know how I should do it.

I'm new to PowerShell so any guidance will be very appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the password to check the contents by converting it to a `PsCredential` object.

Create a SecureString (just for this demo - sounds like you already have this):

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "TopSecretPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
```

Convert to a `PsCredential` object (value of `username` is irrelevant):

```
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", $securePassword)
```

Get the password back:

```
$cleartextPassword = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Check if it is blank:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($cleartextPassword)) 
{ 
    # prompt again
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @boxdog.  I can try that.  For my own education, can you think of a reason why checking the length would be a bad idea?

Comment: I think your method will work with standard SecureString generation techniques (e.g. `Read-Host`) as I don't see any way to pass in 'weird' characters that might cause issues.  However, I'm not sure if there might be a way to have a string of such characters that will have a defined length, but be essentially useless as a password.  In any case, the above technique is extra useful in that you could also apply other tests to the cleartext password to, for example,  enforce password rules.